# How do I send information to an HLSL effect in DirectX 10?

Tags: directx, hlsl, lighting, directx-10, specular

I'd like to send my view vector to an ID3D10Effect variable in order to calculate specular lighting. How do I send a vector or even just scalar values to the HLSL from the running DirectX program? I want to do something like

```
render() {
   //do transformations
   D3DXMatrix view = camera->getViewMatrix();
   basicEffect.setVariable(viewVector, view);
   //render stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your effect, you should have something like:

```
cbuffer {
    float4x4 viewMatrix;
}
```

Then in your render function, before binding the effect:

```
D3DXMatrix view = camera->getViewMatrix();
basicEffect->GetVariableByName("viewMatrix")->AsMatrix()->SetMatrix((float*) &view);
```

As with most effect attribute handles, I would suggest 'caching' the pointer to the variable. Storing the matrix variable in another pointer outside of your render loop, like:

```
ID3D10EffectMatrixVariable* vmViewMatrix = basicEffect->GetVariableByName("viewMatrix")->AsMatrix();
```

And then setting the variable turns into:

```
vmViewMatrix->SetMatrix((float*) &view);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [GetVariableByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173768(VS.85).aspx) to get an interface to the named variable in the HLSL.  Call [AsVector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173735(v=VS.85).aspx) (Note the documentation at this point is wrong.  It returns a pointer!) on  the returned interface to get a vector variable interface and then call [SetFloatVector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173757(v=VS.85).aspx).